# Find class in iframe and update progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple videos in one page. I want to update the progress bar whenever user hits the play button of any video in a single page.

This is my code for video and progress bar.

#### Markup for Progress bar

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0"
       aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Markup for iframe

```
<div>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WnRp8FrXGXU"
          frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

#### Script for progress bar

```
var videos_watched = 0;

$(".video_link").on("click", function() {
  if (!($(this).hasClass("viewed"))) {
    $(this).addClass("viewed");

    videos_watched = videos_watched + 1;
    $("#videos_watched span").html(videos_watched);

    var percent = videos_watched / 4 * 100;
    $(".progress-bar").css("width", percent + "%");
  }
});

$(".progress-bar span").html(percent);
```

Comment: can anyone help me with how to update progress bar when i click on the play button of iframe video.

Comment: You need to know the total number of available videos. It looks like you have a 4. Maybe you should store that in a variable? `progress = (videosWatched / totalVideos) * 100` ?

Comment: how should i update my progress bar with play button of video player.

Comment: my class for iframe tag is "video_link", sorry i have not mentioned in code.